# Is it possible to use Observable<Double>.interval in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Hi I have a question here, all the docs I found on RxSwift so far are using observable interval as below:

```
let subscription = Observable<Int>.interval(0.3, scheduler: scheduler)
    .subscribe { event in
        print(event)
    }

NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)

subscription.dispose()
```

Now I have the need to implement a `Observable<Double>.interval` timer, I would like to a Double value in my subscribeNext calls from Observable.

After change above code to `Double` as a testing, I have an error saying `Type Observable<Double> has no member IntegerLiteralType` , anyone knows how to implement this in RxSwift?

Comment: Do the answers below not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Observable where Element : SignedIntegerType {
    /**
    Returns an observable sequence that produces a value after each period, using the specified scheduler to run timers and to send out observer messages.

    - seealso: [interval operator on reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html)

    - parameter period: Period for producing the values in the resulting sequence.
    - parameter scheduler: Scheduler to run the timer on.
    - returns: An observable sequence that produces a value after each period.
    */
    @warn_unused_result(message="http://git.io/rxs.uo")
    public static func interval(period: RxTimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType)
        -> Observable<E> {
        return Timer(dueTime: period,
            period: period,
            scheduler: scheduler
        )
    }
}
```

The Element Type is `SignedIntegerType`. So you can't use Double.If you want to use double , you can rewrite Timer and associated classes.But I don't suggest to rewrite it.You can think another way to do it.

Comment: thanks kai for your comment, I read this question from RxSwift: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/379 I tried the answers they provided but seems not working for my case, do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure why you would want a sequence of `Double` values, because the value just tells you how many times the interval has passed (it does not tell you the amount of time that has passed). So it makes sense that the value is an `Int`.

But if you really want a sequence of `Double` values you could easily map the `Int` sequence to a `Double` sequence:

```
_ = Observable<Int>.interval(0.4, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .map { Double($0) }
        .subscribeNext { value in
            print(value)
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Which prints:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
...
```